# PKRevealController dim the hidden controller

Tags: ios, ios7, rubymotion

Does anyone has an idea if PKRevealController has a method to add an overlay (dim) effect to the hidden controller when the right/left view slides in ?

https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I saw inside the example code, you can check which kind of state you have for a specific `UIViewController`. Can't you add a new `UIView` make it black with `alpha:0.6` and set it hidden. If the `UIViewController` did change to the state in background, animate the hidden View like

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [OverlayView setHidden:NO];
}];
```

Inside `viewDidAppear` you can check if your **OverlayView** is hidden:YES and animate it to NO.

Comment: This is what I have thought of as a workaround but wanted to check if PKRevealController offers such functionality.Thanks